# Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z^4 + c = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z^4 + c = 0$ where $c = c' + 0i$ for some $c' \in \mathbb{R}$

How could I solve for $z$ in this case? I could convert $z$ into polar co-ordinates and let $z = re^{i\phi}$ and then I'd have $z^4 = r^4 e^{i 4\phi} = -1$ but in that case I'm still now sure how to solve for $r$ and $\phi$.

What is the best method to solve for $z$ in this case?

Comment: @Arthur Sorry I edited the question

Comment: What do you know about complex (square/cube/fourth) roots?

Comment: $c$ is a real number, so you must have that $r^4 = c$ and $4\pi \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$. (because the polar coordinates are unique (well almost unique...))

Comment: @Arthur I know about roots of unity, but I can't apply that in this case since $c \neq -1$

Comment: @Perturbative But most of what you know about roots of unity translates. You solve for $\phi$ the exact same way, and you solve for $r$ the same way you do in the real case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth  roots of $-c$ are simply made up of one fourth root of $ -c$ multiplied by each of the fourth roots of unity, $1,\,-1,\,i,\,-i$.

Now either $-c>0$ or $-c<0$. In the first case, a fourth root is simply $\sqrt[4]{-c}$, and in the second case, it is $\sqrt[4]{c}\:\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=-c$. Then we want to solve
$$
z^4=a
$$
Now think about what $^4$ does to a complex number: It quadruples the angle, and raises the length to the fourth power. So if $a$ has (positive) length $r$, what length must $z$ have? If $a$ has angle $\phi$, what angles can $z$ have?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong,

$z^4 = -c$, so $z = c^\frac{1}{4}.(-1)^\frac{1}{4}$ or $z = c^{1/4}.e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi)}, n \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: You should not use the fractional notation for complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\operatorname{cis}\theta=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.
Then,
\begin{align}
z^4+c&=0 \\
\implies z^4&=-c \\
z^4&=c\operatorname{cis}(\pi+2\pi k) \qquad k\in\mathbb{Z} \\
\implies z&=\sqrt[4]{c}\operatorname{cis}(\pi/4 + \pi k/2) \quad k=0,1,2,3
\end{align}